# Is there any way to get logic app name from workflow_Id?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app subscribed to event grid topic. I just want to indentify the logic app name from endpoint URL . Is there any way to identify ?

I tried to get it from logs analytics workspace using below query , but I am not getting any record in result. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where workflowId_s == "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can query like this, with Azure CLI you could use an Azure Resource Graph query.

```
az graph query -q "where type == 'microsoft.logic/workflows' and properties.accessEndpoint endswith 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'"
```